# "Why would anyone lock the door?" -> meaning of would

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, modal-verbs

If someone says that sentence in the title when they are fumingly slamming the nob, then would "would" in the phrase mean three things below at the same time?

1. I really want to know what were they thinking when they lock the door.
2. Why do some people would always try to lock any door?
3. Why do these kind of people who lock every doors even exist in the world?

Comment: What is meant by "slamming the nob"?

Comment: Not knowing why the person is angry or what door they are talking about, it's impossible to say exactly what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

"Would" here is a *modal verb* and is used after 'why' to ask the reason for something.

The question is why would *anyone* lock the door, so it is as broad a question as possible. The person is asking for a general reason to lock a door. The question is possibly *rhetorical*, as it could mean the person can personally think of no good reason why.

It is different from asking why specific people lock their doors, for example:

> Why do people lock their doors?

This is a more genuine question, not rhetorical. It is arguably extended to *all* people, but as it must be based on the observation that people *do* lock their doors, it only really refers to those people the asker knows about.

Comment: Thanks, so if there maybe any kind of proper contexts are given, would my 3 interpretation could possibly fit as correct meanings respectively? Or are they all totally wrong under any cases at all?

Comment: @dolco I don't think there are contexts where numbers 2 or 3 could fit, because somebody wouldn't use "the" to talk about doors in general.